# tcpdump: "ethertype Unknown"?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

While debugging a DNS problem (apparently UDP packets get lost on the network), I'm stumbling upon many (but not all) "ethertype Unknown" messages such as follows. Tcpdump is run with "-n -i any port 53"

`17:34:43.826196 IP 127.0.0.1.46508 > 127.0.0.1.53: 57861+ A? collector-123.newrelic.com. (44)
17:34:43.826221 IP 127.0.0.1.46508 > 127.0.0.1.53: 20016+ AAAA? collector-123.newrelic.com. (44)
17:34:43.826314 IP 127.0.0.1.53 > 127.0.0.1.46508: 57861 1/0/0 A 50.31.164.223 (60)
17:34:43.826505 IP 82.94.181.250.38280 > 208.78.70.21.53: 4554 AAAA? collector-123.newrelic.com. (44)
17:34:43.826510 Out 00:25:90:4b:94:dc ethertype Unknown (0x0067), length 92: 
        0x0000:  0000 0800 4500 0048 ef3d 4000 4011 2cab  ....E..H.=@.@.,.
        0x0010:  525e b5fa d04e 4615 9588 0035 0034 1f02  R^...NF....5.4..
        0x0020:  11ca 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0d63 6f6c  .............col
        0x0030:  6c65 6374 6f72 2d31 3233 086e 6577 7265  lector-123.newre
        0x0040:  6c69 6303 636f 6d00 001c 0001            lic.com.....
17:34:43.826512 Out 00:25:90:4b:94:dc ethertype Unknown (0x0067), length 92: 
        0x0000:  0000 0800 4500 0048 ef3d 4000 4011 2cab  ....E..H.=@.@.,.
        0x0010:  525e b5fa d04e 4615 9588 0035 0034 1f02  R^...NF....5.4..
        0x0020:  11ca 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0d63 6f6c  .............col
        0x0030:  6c65 6374 6f72 2d31 3233 086e 6577 7265  lector-123.newre
        0x0040:  6c69 6303 636f 6d00 001c 0001            lic.com.....
17:34:43.828629  In 00:1e:13:c1:52:00 ethertype Unknown (0x0067), length 159: 
        0x0000:  0000 0800 4500 008b b1dd 0000 3611 b3c8  ....E.......6...
        0x0010:  d04e 4615 525e b5fa 0035 9588 0077 8a5a  .NF.R^...5...w.Z
        0x0020:  11ca 8400 0001 0000 0001 0000 0d63 6f6c  .............col
        0x0030:  6c65 6374 6f72 2d31 3233 086e 6577 7265  lector-123.newre
        0x0040:  6c69 6303 636f 6d00 001c 0001 c01a 0006  lic.com.........
        0x0050:  0001 0000 0e10 0037 036e 7331 0370 3231  .......7.ns1.p21
        0x0060:  0664 796e 6563 7403 6e65 7400 0c64 6f6d  .dynect.net..dom
        0x0070:  6169 6e2d 6164 6d69 6ec0 1a00 0002 3400  ain-admin.....4.
        0x0080:  000e 1000 0002 5800 093a 8000 000e 10    ......X..:.....`

What would cause these? Could it be related to hardware offloading to the nic? Is it harmful?

Comment: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/16449/high-number-of-unknown-ethertypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is an offset of 4 bytes in the dump. The ethertype is "0800" but tcpdump believes the ethertype is "0045" which is really the beginning of the IP header.

Maybe you are using a VLAN (which adds 4 bytes to the frame). Yes, it can be related to offloading, or to the interface (eg. use eth0.X instead of eth0 where X is the VLAN). And no, it does not sound harmful.